# Dictionary ( Class or Interface Error )

Tags: android, dictionary

I was a new to android studio and I'm to make a little dictionary project for my school. and this error is keeping me crazy cause I cant fix it. please help me

this is the whole code

```
package gricoalvarez.com.kamus;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbkamus";
public static final String INDONESIA = "indonesia";
public static final String INGGRIS= "inggris";
public static final String KETERANGAN = "keterangan";



/Constructor DataKamus untuk initiate database
    public DataKamus(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

public void createTable(SQLiteDatabase db){
   db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS kamus");
   db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE if not exists kamus (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, indonesia TEXT, inggris TEXT, keterangan TEXT);");
}

method generateData untuk mengisikan data ke kamus.
    public void generateData(SQLiteDatabase db){
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put(INDONESIA, "jagung");
    cv.put(INGGRIS, "Corn");
    cv.put(KETERANGAN, "Jagung merupakan tanaman semusim. Satu siklus hidupnya diselesaikan dalam 80-150 hari. Paruh pertama dari siklus merupakan tahap pertumbuhan vegetatif dan paruh kedua untuk tahap pertumbuhan generatif");
    db.insert("kamus", INGGRIS, cv);
    cv.put(INDONESIA, "tomat");
    cv.put(INGGRIS, "Tomato");
    cv.put(KETERANGAN, "tomat merupakan");
    db.insert("kamus", INGGRIS, cv);

    cv.put(INDONESIA, "lari");
    cv.put(INGGRIS, "run");
    cv.put(KETERANGAN, "lari");
    db.insert("kamus", INGGRIS, cv);


}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
 }
}
```

that part of Public void got an error : error illegal type : void

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? Can you post the error?

Comment: Please share a complete snippet and the exact error you're getting. It's almost impossible to help you with the scarce data you provided here.

Comment: @GricoAlvarez where exactly are you getting this error?

Comment: @Mureinik from the line 9 - 12. ( Private to Public ) it said class or interface expected.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the class' definition:

```
package gricoalvarez.com.kamus;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataKamus { // Here!

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbkamus";
    public static final String INDONESIA = "indonesia";
    public static final String INGGRIS= "inggris";
    public static final String KETERANGAN = "keterangan";

    // Rest of the code - constructors, methods, etc..
```